# Running the django tests using fabric

Tags: django, django-admin, fabric, django-unittest

I have a fabric script that attempts to run the tests for an application that I wrote.
It is already installed using setup.py and I am able to import it.
I am following the script I found [here](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine/blob/master/fabfile.py).
My problem is that django-admin doesn't find my app:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/fabric/main.py",
>   line 542, in main
>       commands[name](*args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/envconf/fabfile.py", line 35, in test
>       management.call_command('test', 'envconf')   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 166, in call_command
>       return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 220, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py",
>   line 37, in handle
>       failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/test/simple.py",
>   line 395, in run_tests
>       suite = self.build_suite(test_labels,
>   extra_tests)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/test/simple.py",
>   line 285, in build_suite
>       app = get_app(label)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py",
>   line 140, in get_app
>       raise ImproperlyConfigured("App with label %s could not be found" %
>   app_label)
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
>   App with label envconf could not be
>   found

Here's my code:
    import functools
    import os

```
from fabric.api import local, cd, env
from fabric.contrib.project import rsync_project
from django.conf import settings
from django.core import management

NAME = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(__file__))
ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = os.pathsep.join([ROOT])

env.hosts = ['omer.me']

local = functools.partial(local, capture=False)

def test():
    settings.configure(DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '.',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
        }
    },
    INSTALLED_APPS = ('envconf', ))

    print os.environ
    management.call_command('test', 'envconf')
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem while digging into the code.
For some reason you cannot run the tests if you have no models.py file.

Opened an [issue](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15605) in django's trac.

Comment: Yup, Django tests require a `models.py` file. [Related thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16048978/260365)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I'm not sure, but maybe settings configured wrongly. **NAME** should be the full path to sqlite database file. According docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/settings/#name

Comment: '.' is just fine if you don't really need a database