# Getting rid of empty models.py in django testsuite

Tags: django, django-models, django-testing

I have two pure service apps, that act as servant to my core models. Hence, they do not have any own models.

While the testsuite for the first service runs fine, the second throws the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 
App with label location is missing a models.py module.
```

If I add an empty models.py, the suite runs fine.

I can't spot a difference in terms of architecture / structure between the apps. But I want to get rid of the empty, unneeded models.py.

How would I do that?

Comment: what are you using for your unit tests? The tools that come with Django or something else. Also, can you show the test code causing the test to fail?

Comment: I'm using djangos standard test suite and the mock library.

I don't know what to post (it's over 100 tests), but I have all tests in the `/tests` folder in my app and am importing the tests via the `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** What you ask is now possible. With Django 1.7 you no longer need a `models.py` file. -[release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7/#app-loading-refactor)

*Previously*: Django testing requires every app to have a `models.py` file. It's okay to leave it empty (or with a helpful comment!). [Ticket discussion](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7198) on the matter of apps without models. Direct from the code (added in [1.4](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4/tests/modeltests/empty/tests.py#L28-L29)/still in [1.5](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5/tests/modeltests/empty/tests.py#L29-L30)):

> the test runner won't currently load a test module with no models.py file

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is necessary to include a 'models.py' module on every Django application to make it run properly